# Getting last modified file path from subfolder on Amazon S3. Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, boto3

Good day!!

I need to create a function (or even give the correct arguments to mine) that is able to get the last modified file path of a subfolder inside an AWS S3 bucket.

I normally use this function:

```
def get_file_path(s3, bucket, prefix):
    """
    Getting last modified file in the desired bucket.
    :param bucket_name
    :param prefix 
    :return:
    """
    objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    if 'Contents' in objs:
        objs = objs['Contents']
        print("objs", objs)
        get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))
        last_modified_file_prefix = "/".join([obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)][0].split("/")[:-1])
        logger.info('Last modified file prefix is: %s', last_modified_file_prefix)
        return f"s3://{bucket}/{last_modified_file_prefix}/"
    else:
        return None
```

This way:

```
table_nob = get_file_path(s3,BUSINESS_BUCKET_NAME, "totem/NOB_COD_DIAS/")
```

And It works perfectly. My problem is that this function is created to get the last modified file inside **2-step subfolder**.

So today I'll need a function that gives me that file from a 3-step subfolder. Like this one:

```
table_vols = get_file_path(s3, BUSINESS_BUCKET_NAME, 'everest/consumos/bd_f_consumos_eess/')
```

How would be the function that could work with this 3-step subfolder file?
Or even better, how should I modify my get_file_path to work with this **3-step subfolder** file too?

I tried doing this:

```
    """
    Getting last modified file in the desired bucket.
    :param bucket_name
    :param prefix 
    :return:
    """
    objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    if 'Contents' in objs:
        objs = objs['Contents']
        print("objs", objs)
        get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))
        last_modified_file_prefix = "/".join([obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)][0].split("/")[:-1])
        logger.info('Last modified file prefix is: %s', last_modified_file_prefix)
        return f"s3://{bucket}//{last_modified_file_prefix}/"
    else:
        return None
```

**Changing last 'return'**

But still catching wrong file.

Thank you very much in advance!!!!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output from your function is for the two different prefix inputs?

Comment: Finally the problem was not the prefix, but it reached a maximum of object as Anon commented.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues you're running into:

How you look for objects under a given path will only list the first 1000 objects.  You'll need to use pagination to list all of the objects potentially.  Further, the way you're comparing datetimes depends on local, and you don't need to actually sort the items, just find the newest one.  Here's one way to fix both.

```python
def get_file_path(s3, bucket, prefix):
    """
    Getting last modified file in the desired bucket.
    :param bucket_name
    :param prefix 
    :return:
    """

    # Paginate through the results, that way if a given key contains 
    # more than 1000 items, the correct item is found
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    last_modified_obj = None
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix):
        for cur in page.get("Contents", []):
            # Compare each item in turn, if it's the first comparision, or the
            # given item is newer, the use it
            if last_modified_obj is None or cur['LastModified'] > last_modified_obj['LastModified']:
                last_modified_obj = cur

    if last_modified_obj is None:
        # Nothing was found
        return None
    else:
        # Pull out the prefix of the given item
        prefix = last_modified_obj['Key'].rpartition('/')[0]
        logger.info(f'Last modified file prefix is: {prefix}')
        # Return the S3 URI, special casing the case where the prefix is empty and
        # doesn't need a trailing slash
        return f"s3://{bucket}/{prefix}{'/' if len(prefix) else ''}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed that was the problem. 
Although it costs me a little to realise there is a '3' needed in the last return hahah. You helped!!! 
I'll use this function instead of the previous to skip this problem over the rest of get_file_path functions.